# kubernetes replicaSet shutdown policy

Tags: linux, docker, java, tomcat, kubernetes

Kubernetes use TERM signal on count down replicaSet .
this is so dangerous for my application .
I use Tomcat application server and this application server has own shutdown mechanism for terminating application server.
when i send operating system (Linux) signals (9,15,...) to jvm , JVM does not know what do with threads inside jvm , so threads killed before successfully completed.

```
Request -----> BackEnd API -----> [Process] -----> Response
                                      ^   
                   Send TERM (Signal) while thread doing Process
```

Is there any way to change kubernetes container shutdown mechanism ?
I want kubernetes use :

```
catalina.sh stop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubernetes lifecycle is good solution for problems like this :
[Container Lifecycle Hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/)

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this would be with dumb-init.

Building containers, dumb-init is usually a good practice, dealing with zombies among others. In your case, it would also allow to re-map signals.

In your Dockerfile, you would have something like

```
CMD ["dumb-init", "--rewrite", "15:28", "/app/start.sh"]
```

Check with `kill -l`, `SIGINT` should be number `15`.

Then, in your start script, you may trap the `SIGWINCH` (`28`) signal:

```
#!/bin/sh

trap "cd /app ; catalina.sh stop" SIGWINCH

[your startup script]
exec $JAVA_HOME/bin/java ...
```

---

edit, as I can see another answer was accepted: of course, container lifecycle hooks could sound nice.

On one hand, they've been here for about a year: may not be usable depending on your cluster version.

And then, you'll realize they only run upon API driven terminations, which could be an issue.

Comment: I can not understand ! Why SIGWINCH signal ?!!!!

Comment: pick any signal you can catch.